# Logical OR for two different fields in $where queries in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How do you do a query like the one below, where I want hotels in London OR hotels which have hilton in their name?

This query 
db.hotels.find({$where : "name = /hilton/i  || city = /london/i"})

gives such an error
error: { "$err" : "$where compile error" }

Both queries separately work ok:
db.hotels.find({$where : "city = /london/i"})
db.hotels.find({$where : "name = /hilton/i"})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.hotels.find({
    $where: "/london/i.test(this.city) || /hilton/i.test(this.hotel)"
})
```

**NOTE**
As far as I understand `$where` does a per-document evaluation, so it can be pretty slow. If you'd have a single attribute, I'd suggested smth like

```
db.hotels.find({name: /(hilton|london)/i})
```

Comment: But I am looking for two different fields :( otherwise the second query would be fine

Comment: perfect now :) thanks... and yes you are also right about the performance... it is rather slow
doing two separate queries is faster than one combined

Answer (score 7):

Now, that mongodb supports $or condition, you can do this like:

```
db.hotels.find( { $or: [ { name: /hilton/i }, 
                         { city: /london/i } 
                       ] 
              } );
```