# MongoDB query where at least one document satisfies each condition

Tags: mongodb

I have a need to query a set of documents in MongoDB to find all the items that satisfy at least one of N conditions (basically an OR) but also at least one document in the result should satisfy each of the N conditions.

So for example, if my conditions are `[field1=aaa, field2=bbb]` then I want a query that will return documents `[D1, D2, ..., Dm]` so that every D matches the expression `field1=aaa OR field2=bbb`
along with every condition having at least one D that matches to it.

So a good result would be:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "123",
        "field1": "aaa"
    },
    {
        "_id": "456",
        "field2": "bbb"
    }

]
```

And a bad result would be:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "123",
        "field1": "aaa"
    },
    {
        "_id": "456",
        "field1": "aaa"
    }

]
```

Any idea how such a query could be performed in Mongo?

EDIT - to clarify, the conditions might be quite complex, looking into nested fields inside complex JSONs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB query with an 'or' condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008032/mongodb-query-with-an-or-condition)

Comment: Afraid not. A basic or does not guarantee that each condition was matched at least once. I could get a result where all documents matched the first condition and the or query would still be valid.